# Circleci: only run some tests for a specific branch

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

We are using CircleCI and we have two test suites: one of the them is fast and the other one is slow. We would like to run the first suite when any branch is commited, but only run the second suite when commits are made to the `master` branch. Is this possible? How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value of `$CIRCLE_BRANCH` and determine which mode to use in your *circle.yml* file. Something like `if` in bash should be enough.

[Here](https://circleci.com/docs/environment-variables) are all the available env vars.